# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary. I will be working with candidates to determine a time for the event.

***The Town Hall Chat took place Wednesday the 5th at 18:00:00Z UTC / 1:00 PM EST. A digest can be found [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest).***

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 3rd-5th of December. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=android.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- Priority for scheduling is generally towards the greatest number of candidate openings as well as the earliest. Candidates who cannot show up during the live event will still be able to answer all questions posted, they will just do so at their earliest convenience.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: If I cannot attend the chat, can I post questions for the candidates here (or somewhere)?

Comment: @AlEverett You could post them here, yes, and I'll ask them during the town hall chat on your behalf.

Comment: When will you be sending these emails?

Comment: @TheAndroNerd Sometime today.

Comment: @Grace Note Ok, thanks.

Comment: I will try to attend

Comment: As candidates, what if we are unable to attend?

Comment: There is nothing ill if you cannot attend the live event, @jlehenbauer. After the event, the questions will remain in the room and you can answer them, ideally at the soonest opening in your own schedule - the digest will typically be delayed until all responses are gotten in.